# ValueError: Could not find root within given tolerance

Tags: python, sympy, equation, solver, valueerror

I am trying to solve a nonlinear equation using `nsolve` function for arrays of 1000 item. Unfortunately, the below error appears:

```
ValueError: Could not find root within given tolerance. (0.0000219625112807593736122 > 2.16840434497100886801e-19)
Try another starting point or tweak arguments.
```

However, I tried to solve the same equation for only one item instead of 1000 items and it works!

I am using Google Collaboratory and the below code:

````
!pip install sympy
!pip install numpy
!pip install matplotlib

from math import *
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import symbols, Eq, sin,cos, tan, cot, pi, nsolve
import random

def convert_to_radian(angle):
  return (angle*(22/7))/180

No_Geo_factor_values = 1000
Geo_factor_range_low , Geo_factor_range_high  = 0 , 0.0481

Geo_factor_list= []
for index in range(No_Geo_factor_values):
  Geo_factor = float(random.uniform(Geo_factor_range_low , Geo_factor_range_high))
  Geo_factor_list.append(Geo_factor)


alpha_2_min = symbols('alpha_2_min')
alpha_2_min_list = []
for index in range(1000):
  alpha_2_min_sol= nsolve(-(Geo_factor_list[index]) + ((1/4) * ((2/ tan(convert_to_radian(alpha_2_min))) + tan (2*convert_to_radian(alpha_2_min)))**(-1)), alpha_2_min, 10)
  alpha_2_min_list.append(alpha_2_min_sol)

alpha_2_list = []
for index in range(1000):
  alpha_2_selected = alpha_2_min_list[index] + 1
  alpha_2_list.append(alpha_2_selected)

alpha_1_var = symbols('alpha_1_var')
alpha_1_list = []

for index in range(1000):
  alpha_1 =  nsolve(( -(Geo_factor_list[index]) + (1/4)* (tan(convert_to_radian(alpha_1_var))) * (tan(convert_to_radian(alpha_2_min_list[index]))) * (1/(tan((convert_to_radian(alpha_1_var))+convert_to_radian(alpha_2_min_list[index]) )))), alpha_1_var , 10)
  alpha_1_list.append(alpha_1) ```
````

Comment: I ran the code locally with latest sympy master and didn't see any error.

Comment: Please never use `from numpy import *`, especially not when you also do `from math import *`. This leads to many name conflicts and a lot of confusion.  It gets completely unmanageable when you also import the same and similar functions from sympy. Note that `numpy` and `math` can't work with `sympy` symbols, and `sympy` can't work with `numpy` and `math` functions. Further, note that `22/7` is a rather bad approximation to `pi`, especially when you already imported `pi`

Comment: I tried solving this equation using solve function instead of nsolve and it works.